# AngularJS retrive data that initialize at the blade in the controller

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, smart-table

I have a table in Laravel Blade which has initialized a value which i want to access in the controller so as to send to a function make an API call. Question is how i access the id sent

```
app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'MyCall','id','TableState', function ($scope, MyCall, id,TableState) {

    $scope.displayed = [];

    $scope.callServer = function callServer(tableState)
    {
        return TableState.renderTable($scope, tableState, MyCall.getRecipientCalls(tableState, $scope.id));
    };

}]
);
```

my blade **code**;

```
<div ng-controller="MyController" ng-init="id ='{!! $mycalls->id !!}'">
```

want to pass the id from above to the controller and view in in *getRecipientCalls* function...

Answer (score 0):

solved by using the **$scope**

```
return TableState.renderTable($scope, tableState, MyCall.getRecipientPositions(tableState, $scope.id));
```

and remove the call in the properties;

```
app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'MyCall','TableState', function ($scope, MyCall,TableState) {
```